# Determine if the sequences of intervals, are a set of nested intervals $\{I_n\}=\{\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n}\}$

Tags: analysis

Determine if the sequences of intervals, are a set of nested intervals $\{I_n\}=\{\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n}\}$

How can I solve it?? My teacher dont want to explain me... First I calculate the firsts intervals
$I_1=[1/2,2/1]$

$I_2=[2/3,3/2]$

$I_3=[3/4,4/3]$

and so....

But I need to check to properties first that one interval its inside of other interval and second the lenght of intervals must be 0... I have more exercise like this, please help me to resolve the others.

Comment: How to solve what? You are checking if $I_{n+1} \subset I_n$?

Comment: $I_n$ its an interval where the limits are sup n/(n+1) and inf (n+1)/n

Answer (score 2):

I take it that you’re trying to show that if $$I_n=\left[\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}n\right]$$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then $\langle I_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a nested sequence of intervals. Clearly

$$\frac{n}{n+1}<1<\frac{n+1}n$$

for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so each $I_n$ really is a non-trivial closed interval. To show that $I_n\supseteq I_{n+1}$, i.e., that

$$\left[\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}n\right]\supseteq\left[\frac{n+1}{n+2},\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right]$$

you must show that

$$\frac{n}{n+1}\le\frac{n+1}{n+2}<\frac{n+2}{n+1}\le\frac{n+1}n\;.\tag{1}$$

The first and last inequalities in $(1)$ are actually equivalent, so you can prove them simultaneously; the proof is a straightforward algebraic manipulation, which I’ll leave to you.